# Any libraries to aid weird shaped source code programming

Tags: language-agnostic, obfuscation

Any libraries to aid writing programs with source code shaped like drawings
(such as http://www.ioccc.org/1998/banks.c or http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/e105e5d339edec01). For any language.

Comment: I hope not. A library is like a tool box, one that contains all the right tools for a job, such as changing the oil in your car, or the tire. libraries may have similar bits of code, such a car jack/lift would be used to change your oil or your tire. formatting source code is not something useful to source code... other then reading it. Your examples have 99% certainly been done by hand. You could make a plug-in for something like notepad++ to this possibly, or a simple console application to 'parse' a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second link made my day :D And it really works!

If you want to play with source code, perl is your friend! Have a look at http://search.cpan.org/~asavige/Acme-EyeDrops-1.55/lib/Acme/EyeDrops.pm for an example. I know you want a language agnostic tool, but I don't think such a thing exists.

Comment: yeah, that link is awesome:))

Comment: I was not looking for a language agnostic tool, but libraries that make it even easier to do this sort of thing (say by having certain shapes for functions/objects or even better something like ACME::EyeDrops, that looks really amazing) (answers from any languages are fine).